# I have a button and an icon inside a function can be lauched with. How can I drag the button without triggering the icon?

Tags: javascript, angular, button, event-handling, mouse

If I touch the icon  and drag the button, then the functions triggered by the icon must not be launched. What must I do?

```
<div>
    <button type="button" class="fixed-button wobble" [style.background]="changeColorService.defaultStyles.firstDesignBackgroundColor" [appMovable]="true">
      <mat-icon [style.color]="changeColorService.defaultStyles.firstDesignFontColor" *ngIf="!(changeKagListIcon)" (click)="openKagListDialog()" matTooltip="KAG-Liste öffnen" [appMovable]="true">dvr</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon [style.color]="changeColorService.defaultStyles.firstDesignFontColor" *ngIf="changeKagListIcon" (click)="dialog.closeAll()" matTooltip="KAG-Liste schließen" [appMovable]="true">close</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you mean, but consider to call `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
    <button (click)="specialFnc()">
      <mat-icon (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"></mat-icon> 
    </button>
```

If you click the icon the specialFnc won't get called. So if you like this behavior, for the drag event - just stop the event chain at the desired point.

I don't know which directive `[appMovable]` is, but within the drag handling you have to call stopPropagation.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript **event.stopPropagation()** will help child event bubbling on Parent element Onclick events.

Example,

```
<button (onclick)="stopChildTrigger($event)">
   <mat-icon><mat-icon>
</button>

stopChildTrigger(e){
   e. stopPropagation();
}
```